# vb.net Discord Bot onMessage

Tags: vb.net

I would like the bot to reply to me only as PM.
e.g. I send the bot as PM !say 1
Then the bot should only reply in PM 2.

But the bot only recognizes a message in the channel, not in the PM.

```
Private Async Function onMessage(message As SocketMessage) As Task
    Dim user = TryCast(message.Author, SocketGuildUser)
    If message.Source <> MessageSource.Bot And message.Content.StartsWith("!") Then
        If message.Content.StartsWith("!say 1") And DirectCast(message.Author, SocketGuildUser).Roles.ToList.Contains(DirectCast(message.Channel, IGuildChannel).Guild.GetRole(91586140315277)) Then

            Await message.Channel.SendMessageAsync("2")
            Await user.SendMessageAsync("2")
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: What do you mean by `the bot only recognizes a message in the channel`? Does it only **reply** to you in the channel or does it only **receive** messages when you send them in a channel, but not when you send in PM?

Comment: yep, the bot reply only in the channel not in the PM (Message)

Comment: You should check to see if you an exception is being thrown. There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the code. If Direct Messages are disabled in the server, the bot won't be able to send messages.

Comment: I get the error at

`code`If DirectCast(message.Author, SocketGuildUser).Roles.ToList.Contains(DirectCast(message.Channel, IGuildChannel).Guild.GetRole(Botroleid.Text)) Then`code`

System.InvalidCastException: "The object of type "Discord.WebSocket.SocketUnknownUser" cannot be converted to type "Discord.WebSocket.SocketGuildUser"."

Comment: If you are executing the command in a DM, you cannot convert the user to a GuildUser

Comment: And how can I do that, that it also goes in the PM?